# Configure MediaWiki responses with and without domain part?

Tags: mediawiki

We are running an internal MediaWiki server. The wiki server has a PKIX certificate with the following names (the certificate is well formed per [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) and [CA/B Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/)):

- IP Address
- wiki
- wiki.example.com

Additionally, the wiki server's `LocalSettings.php` has the following:

- `$wgServer = "//wiki.example.com"`

The line above is protocol agnostic, and allows things to work as expected with both HTTP and HTTPS.

We visit the wiki server in one of three ways:

- https://10.1.2.10/wiki
- https://wiki/wiki
- https://wiki.example.com/wiki

When we use `https://10.1.2.10/wiki` or `https://wiki/wiki`, the CSS is not fetched by a browser because it violates the Same Origin Policy. `10.1.2.10` and `wiki` and `wiki.example.com` are different origins to a browser, so the CSS linked with `wiki.example.com` due to `$wgServer` are not fetched. An example of missing CSS is shown below:

[image]

**Question**: How do I configure the MediaWiki server such that an IP address can be used and the domain part is optional?

**Examples**: if the server receives a request for `10.1.2.10/wiki`, then its responses should *use* `10.1.2.10` (and not `wiki` or `wiki.example.com`). If the server receives a request for `wiki/wiki`, then its responses should *lack* the `example.com`. And if the server receives a request for `wiki.example.com/wiki`, then its responses should *include* the `example.com`.

Comment: You can get unset [`$wgServer`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) (will be set dynamically that way) and set [`$wgCanonicalServer`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCanonicalServer) instead. This will probably not work if you cache your HTML, though.

Comment: Alternatively, you might try to set [`$wgStylePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStylePath)/[`$wgLoadScript`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLoadScript)/[`$wgResourceBasePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceBasePath) dynamically.